# How to rewrite sql query to spark with not exists operator

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have sql query

```
load1.sqlContext()
                .sql("select object_id, parent_id, object_id as root_id, attr_id, attr_name, value from load l1 where not exists (select 1 from load l2 where l2.object_id = l1.parent_id)").show(false);
```

result query
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA2HB.png)

ried to rewrite but get an exception

```
Dataset<Row> test = load1.select(
        functions.col("object_id"),
        functions.col("parent_id"),
        functions.col("object_id").as("root_id"),
        functions.col("attr_id"),
        functions.col("attr_name"),
        functions.col("value"));
test.where(not(exists(load1.col("object_id"), x -> x.equalTo(test1.col("parent_id"))))).show(false);
```

exception

```
cannot resolve 'exists(load.object_id, lambdafunction((x_1 = load.parent_id), x_1))' due to argument data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array type, however, 'load.object_id' is of string type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of test.where try using an left anti join

```
test.join(load1.select("object_id").withColumnRenamed("object_id", "parent_id"), "parent_id", "left_anti")
    .show(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got exception 
Reference 'parent_id' is ambiguous, could be: test.parent_id, parent_id.
I tweaked it a bit and it works, thanks 
test.join(load1, col("load.object_id").equalTo(col("test.parent_id")), "left_anti").show(false);

Comment: Glad to hear that it works, an up-vote would help.